# Single word request: cancer patients' prognosis is bad (serious)

Tags: single-word-requests, british-english, academia

I, a non-native English speaker, am writing an academic summary in medicine and I am trying to find a word for describing that cancer patients prognosis is bad. However, "bad" isn't an appropriate word for an academic context. The best I can think about is the first example below but is "serious" a suitable word in this case?

> Cancer prognosis is **serious**.

> Cancer prognosis is **not always good**.

> Cancer prognosis is ________

Could you please help me with a suitable word?

Comment: What aspect of bad are you trying to convey? That it might be fatal, that it needs to be handled competently, etc.? There are a couple of dozen synonyms for bad that could apply here.

Comment: Good point. I edited the OP a bit, adding the third sentence at the end of the first paragraph. Does it help?

Comment: Every word has a meaning. *Serious* means serious, but not necessarily *fatal;* *bad* could mean anything from just the wrong side of *good* all the way to *dying tomorrow.* **What is it that you want to convey?** I suspect that there are standard terms in medicine, in which case a generalist English site might not be the best one (although a question written according to [guidelines](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info) is on-topic here). There is [medicalsciences.se] for a specialist viewpoint. Do check their help pages.

Comment: Cancer is usually described, in the U S, in stages, which have specific meanings, e.g., it has or has not spread here or there. It’s not a question of parsing words like serious and poor.

Comment: If "'bad' isn't an appropriate word for an academic context" then I've been writing inappropriately for about 50 years.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use ***poor***.

> Cancer prognosis is ***poor***.

About ***prognosis***, [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/prognosis) says it means:

> the prospect of survival and recovery from a disease as anticipated from the usual course of that disease or indicated by special features of the case

The example it gives is

> The prognosis is ***poor*** because of the accompanying cardiovascular
> disease.

This [NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=prognosis%20is%20poor%2C%20prognosis%20is%20bad%2C%20prognosis%20is%20unfavourable&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cprognosis%20is%20poor%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cprognosis%20is%20bad%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cprognosis%20is%20unfavourable%3B%2Cc0) also shows that charcaterising ***prognosis*** as ***poor*** is the most common:

[image]

It is also true if you search with [a wild cart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=prognosis%20is%20%2A&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cprognosis%20is%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bprognosis%20is%20good%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bprognosis%20is%20not%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bprognosis%20is%20very%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bprognosis%20is%20poor%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bprognosis%20is%20favorable%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bprognosis%20is%20always%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bprognosis%20is%20bad%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bprognosis%20is%20unfavorable%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bprognosis%20is%20more%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bprognosis%20is%20generally%3B%2Cc0).